Convergence/divergence of the series $\sum\frac{n}{(n+1)^{2}}$
The Question
Conclude the convergence/divergence of the series $\sum\frac{n}{(n+1)^{2}}$.
My attempt
I used derivative test to show that the function $\frac{x}{(x+1)^{2}}$ is a monotonically decreasing function after certain point, say $p$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then I did the following integral $\int_{p}^{\infty}\frac{xdx}{(x+1)^{2}} = ln(x+1)+\frac{1}{x+1}\Big|_{p}^{\infty} $  which doesn't exist.
Is it correct? Also, is there a more elegant way to do this, the analysis done to show that the function is monotonic took a fair amount of time. Is there a way to do it by comparison test? Also on the same note, what are some series that I should keep in mind to apply comparison test handily to conclude divergence, convergence quickly.

I woud limit-compare to $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$.

What does "limit-compare" mean?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Your approach works. But it's way simpler to use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac n{(n+1)^2}}{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}=1.$$Therefore, since the harmonic series diverges, your series diverges too.

So, if two sequences are asymptotically same, the series corresponding to them, diverge/converge together?

Yes, assuming that we are only dealing with real numbers greater than $0$ here.

Noticing that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum \frac{n}{(n+1)^2} & >\sum \frac{n}{(n+n)^2} =\frac{1}{4} \sum \frac{1}{n} ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and $ \displaystyle  \sum \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, therefore $ \displaystyle  \sum \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$ is divergent too.

If you know that
$\sum \dfrac1{n}$
diverges then
$\dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}
\ge \dfrac1{2n}
$,
which is true for
$n \ge 3$,
shows that
$\sum \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}
$
also diverges.
To show
$\dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}
\ge \dfrac1{2n}
$ for $n \ge 3$,
cross-multiplying gives
$2n^2\ge (n+1)^2
$
or
$n^2-2n-1\ge 0
$
or
$(n-1)^2 \ge 2$.

Assume that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$$ converges, so that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$$ converges (this is because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, hence by shifting, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ converges).
We get that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}$$ converges, which is a contradiction to the divergence of the harmonic series (again, by shifting).
